# Any fast way to take mySQL table and create Hibernate beans

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

The firm I just started at has to take about 200 MySQL tables and make Java, Hibernate Beans from them. We are working on Spring MVC Web projects.  Does anyone know of any tool or product that will credit the Java code for us from mySQL tables>

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (and Hibernate Tools) has a lot of functionality for auto-generating code. I assume the other IDE's do as well. Walk-through: http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables

Comment: it looks like it creat java code and sometype of files <tablename>.hbm.xml.  I never seen this

Comment: I know in eclipse after setting a project to include the Hibernate libraries I have just right clicked on tables in the database explorer and selected `generate hibernate classes`. I know it was fairly out of the box as I produced a working demo in a couple hours for a presentation I was giving. Worked really easily - if no one else answers shortly I will load eclipse and try it out again.

Comment: which version of eclipse... I dont see a database explorer

Comment: @techsjs2013 Ah - sorry was running MyEclipse. I am uncertain of how much of the functionality I would have used was MyEclipse versus Eclipse. Off hand, I have typically found MyEclipse worth the small subscription fee.